# List View -> Group by Resources

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to show the events in the list view grouped by resources, just like it can be done on the timeline view?

Comment: I don't think so, no. You can do it for agenda views (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view) but there's no feature yet for list views. You'd have to code this yourself, unfortunately, or make a feature request and wait to see if it gets implemented. TBH I can't quite visualise how you'd expect such a list to look? The list is inherently just a vertical list of events. How would the grouping appear?

Comment: @Adyson 
It should look like this:
resourceA (event 1 & event 2 below), resourceB (event 3 & event 4 below)
...

Comment: Ok I see. Well that kinda makes some sense I guess. But yeah there's no functionality for that at the moment that I know of.